# Wrong result from Optim.jl

Tags: optimization, julia

By chance, I found this problem when using Optim.jl

```
using Optim
f(x)= -abs(1-x/3.5+(2*sin(2*pi*(x-1.75))-sin(2*pi*x))/(7*pi))
res = optimize(x->f(x), 1.75, 3.5)
```

After running this code in Julia, I had the following results

```
Optim.minimizer(res) # This gives 2.8524
Optim.minimum(res)   # This gives -2.7597e-01
```

But the correct answer should be that the minimum value of f(x) over [1.75, 3.5] is -0.5617 at x = 1.8524 (this correct result was confirmed by using command in wolframalpha.com).

I also tried with different algorithm (GoldenSection()) as

```
optimize(x->f(x), 1.75, 3.5, GoldenSection())
```

But the result it gave is also wrong.

Perhaps, I may wrongly use the commands of Optim.jl. Please, have a look and help me to get the correct answer from using Optim.jl.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not unimodal, so you need another algorithm. If you want to use Optim.jl you can use e.g. box constrained simulated annealing:

```
julia> Optim.optimize(x -> f(x[1]), [1.75], [3.5], [2.0], SAMIN(), Optim.Options(iterations=10^4))
================================================================================
SAMIN results
==> Normal convergence <==
total number of objective function evaluations: 6826

     Obj. value:     -0.5616838582

       parameter      search width
         1.85242           0.00000
================================================================================

 * Status: failure

 * Candidate solution
    Final objective value:     -5.616839e-01

 * Found with
    Algorithm:     SAMIN

 * Convergence measures
    |x - x'|               = NaN ≰ 0.0e+00
    |x - x'|/|x'|          = NaN ≰ 0.0e+00
    |f(x) - f(x')|         = NaN ≰ 0.0e+00
    |f(x) - f(x')|/|f(x')| = NaN ≰ 0.0e+00
    |g(x)|                 = NaN ≰ 0.0e+00

 * Work counters
    Seconds run:   0  (vs limit Inf)
    Iterations:    6826
    f(x) calls:    6826
    ∇f(x) calls:   0
```

Comment: What does `Status: failure` mean?

Comment: You can ignore it. It is hardcoded as you can see here https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/Optim.jl/blob/01b49c7dc4ec37f97d87118f03877c64e3da9a8c/src/multivariate/solvers/constrained/samin.jl#L321. It is a bit confusing indeed. You should use the information shown in a line below SAMIN results.

Comment: Thank you for your workaround suggestion. But I think the "not unimodal" is not the true reason, since for another "not unimodal" problem (shown below), the Brent's algorithm and Golden Section algorithm both lead to correct answer ```using Optim; f(x)= -abs(1-x/3+(2*sin(2*pi*(x-1.5))-sin(2*pi*x))/(6*pi)); optimize(x->f(x), 1.5, 3)```

Comment: Yes, they might converge to the optimum for some problems if you are lucky. What I say is that these algorithms were designed with the assumption that the problem is unimodal, see https://julianlsolvers.github.io/Optim.jl/stable/ (the "What" section).